# verification system

Tags: java, .net, authentication, opencv

I am developing a facelogin application. I could able to identify who the person with 80% accuracy. I need to differentiate between

1. A person standing infront of camera and
2. A poster of the same person kept infront of the camera.

Is this possible?

I did the login using opencv

Help is welcomed from any programming language.
Thanks

Comment: I very much doubt it is possible, but I'd be interested in any answers

Comment: Well, I guess you could somehow flash the user(change the amount of light emitted towards users eyes) and check for users pupils reaction. :)

Comment: Require the user to stay still, analyse their face for authorization, then require them to turn their head left and then right and take seperate analysis of each side of their head. Since they can't do this with a flat poster it should stop any falsification. In the event that they have access to a picture of all 3 sides of a person (front, left, right), just detect if the picture changed much between each view (i.e. did they drop the poster and put up another one? If so, decline their login)

Comment: as m.edmondson said its very much impossible right now, as the camera has no depth (e.g. its a 2D representation of a 3D world). You can try and use 2 or more cameras, like they do in 3D movie making, but the technology is not there to help you...

Comment: @Tom Glenn what would stop them from showing 3 different pictures?

Comment: @Sigtran read my updated comment. The analysis could detect that the body (chest, arms) stay in the same position and that only the head moves.

Comment: @Tom Glenn well, another way would be to create a big poster with a few head locations, leaving the body the same / etc and twist it in the tube, then rotate as needed... I hope you get the idea... :P

Comment: The best might be to utilize more then one biometric system - e.g. get a finger print and an eye scan on top of what you have :)

Comment: @Sigtran With your method, for a moment (even if brief) the head would completely disappear/be dislodged from the body. I would like to imagine that the developer would be competent enough to detect this (as I mentioned in a previous comment) and therefore decline authorization. If we are being honest with ourselves, this kind of authorization will NEVER be foolproof (not with a simple webcam), but if the OP is willing to put the effort in, it could be at least partially-secure.

Comment: @Tom Glenn you are right, the head would disappear, if you are not quick enough... but cameras dont have a huge refresh rate, so any kind of motor, rotating it quicker then the refresh rate could successfully authenticate... In any case as you have said this is not foolproof and only adding additional security will help.

Comment: If the user used a bust (sculpture) instead of a poster or their own face, would *that* be OK?

Answer (score 1):

Take multiple snapshots in short succession. The facial expression on a photo does not change, the face on a photo does not blink with the eyelids and extrapolating the relative depth of the facial elements by means of tiny changes in angle between the snapshots yields a distinct result for photos.

If you can use 2 cameras, calculate the transformation between shots taken by both cameras at the same time. This transformation should be different for plane surfaces and faces (even though you might not be able to extrapolate the actual threedimensional structure).

Comment: That's prejudicial to people in comas & the 'life challenged', expect to hear from the lawyers of the first, and the mediums of the second. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Any such method can be fooled by several videorecords, showing the same person in different positions. For example, you may ask a person to turn around, and this can be recorded and submitted to your program. In the same way, you may decide to, for example, highlight person's face with external light sources, but this also can be recorded and reproduced.

My advice is - do several auth movement series (e.g. nod, head-bobbing, closing eyes, etc) - more is better, then ask user to execute one or more of them in some random order pretty fast. You also may log and count insuccessful auth attempts. Then you will be notified, when someone missordered records for a few times.

Comment: This could still be fooled with pre-recorded footage of the user and some clever software to detect what the page is asking the user to do (A simple screen scraper?) and automatically play the correct video footage. The fact is, it is impossible to completely secure a system that relies on a simple webcam and some 2D image processing.